# Can you ditch the attribution for own content clause from the Terms of Service?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, legal, copyright, terms-of-service

Deep in the bowels of the [SE Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) you will find the following sentence (in section 3.  Subscriber Content), with one clause highlighted by yours truly:

> In the event that You post or otherwise use Subscriber Content outside of the Network or Services, **whether such Subscriber Content was created by You or others**, You agree that You will follow the attribution rules of the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license as follows:
>
> ... standard attribution rules...

I have posted a ***lot*** of content on Stack Exchange. I moderate for one of your sites... But I don't see why I'm expected to give your site attribution for my work if I wanted to post it elsewhere (eg on my Blog). Isn't it enough that I'm answering your users' questions in the first place?

I think the highlighted phrase is unnecessary. It's certainly not a legal requirement (you only demand a irrevocable license for the content, it's still *ours* to re-license as we wish) so having that phrase, as it is, only serves to trip people up if they do dare post it elsewhere.

I do see what I'm sure is your technical argument (it's easier to police infringing sites because they're *all* infringing if they don't attribute) but 99% of the infringing sites are mass-clones, easy to distinguish from single post copies.

It's not the in the spirit of Creative Commons and the freedoms that were advertised when SO and SE were started. Impinging on users freedoms outside Stack Exchange is certainly not a good reward for the people making your sites viable in the first place.

This can be remedied with a quick replacement of the highlighted portion to something like this:

> In the event that You post or otherwise use Subscriber Content outside of the Network or Services, **that was not entirely created by You**, You agree that You will follow the attribution rules of the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license as follows

Comment: I believe you are indeed correct that you still own your content and can relicence it under whatever licence you see fit

Comment: I noted that it's not so much a copyright infringement issue but Stack Exchange could susupend your account if you posted your own content outside of SE without attribution. That's what the TOS does. "Break our rules and you're out" sort of a thing.

Comment: I *suspect* this is in place due to the collaborative nature of so much of these sites, and a desire to avoid ugly situations where (for instance) someone posts something for review, collects feedback and corrections, and then tries to "take it private" so to speak. (Yes, this has come up a few times) I'll ping our resident pseudo-lawyer about this though.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm certain that's entirely right. A lawyer stuffed it in there for Stack Exchange's convenience. My point is, that's it's not convenient for the person who gave up their time to write it. (And thanks for prodding this on).

Comment: An interesting side effect of this would presumably be; I write a program, I have a problem with it, I post a snippet in a question on Stack overflow. Now I have to worry about putting attribution to stack overflow into my own program (even if I get no answers or only use the concepts from the answers)

Comment: [Related question on MathOverflow](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/952/problematic-phrasing-of-stack-exchange-terms-of-service)

Comment: Great job digging this up

Comment: Yay! This is now fixed.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

### Update: We didn't just cut it from the [TOS](https://stackexchange.com/legal). Given that the old wording understandably concerned people, we  wanted to be crystal clear, so we literally reversed it.

The old phrase:

> whether such Subscriber Content was created by You or others,

has been changed to:

> with the **exception** of content entirely created by You,

We could have just cut it, but wanted to make it explicitly clear that users can re-post their own content elsewhere as they see fit.

---

### Philosophy:  Your content is yours.

**You give up one big thing by posting it here:**

- Your right to stop us (and others who see it here) from sharing it with others who can be helped by it, provided they include the required attribution.

### Posting your content here *should not in any way* restrict your rights to use or post it yourself.

To be clear, we did **not** intend to apply wacky requirements that you link back to us when you post *your own content* that you generously shared with the world on our site.

---

Comment: I understand. While you're talking with legal, it'd be worth mentioning @probablyPekka's answer about conformity with Creative Commons' own licensing requirements.

Comment: @oli, we'll make sure to include that in the conversation, but assuming we can excise that whole line, it should obviate that concern.

Comment: While at it, could you also please clarify how ownership is applied in practice? For example, I post a (non CW) post, someone edits it for clarification or might even completely rewrite it from scratch to restate my question. Do I still hold the ownership of the final post as is implied by being the owner of the post? What happens if a post turns CW by too many edits? etc.

Comment: @Kaveh That's *fairly* simple... What you own is based on what *you* write. CW itself has no effect on the copyright status but other people's contributions transform the current version into a derivative work. If they are minor, you could claim them back under fair use, if they are major you could lose any claim to the "current version" (eg they replace all your text). No amount of editing impedes your ability to go back to the original version and take that though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jaydles. It's nice to see that the SE legal team understands our concerns and is willing to let them be addressed in such a clear fashion. This is a case of Doing the Right Thing and I applaud SE for making sure it's clear.

Comment: @JonathanGarber, thanks, I really appreciate the feedback, but the truth is that WE'RE grateful for everyone's contributions here to helping others - the last thing we'd want is an author to feel that their good deeds here in any way reduced their ability to share elsewhere, even if it was just an attribution requirement.

Comment: does this mean that we can use our own content (questions in particular) for commercial purposes without any attribute or anything?

Comment: What happens if you delete your account after cross posting some of your own answers to a personal blog? I'm not clear how deleting your account affects ownership of the material.

Answer (score 54):

That clause contradicts everything we've ever been told about posting on Stack Overflow, which was supposed to be happening under the nonexclusive CC-Wiki license. [Creative Commons' FAQ](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_enter_into_separate_agreements_or_understandings_with_users_outside_the_scope_of_the_license.3F)  state:

> Q: Can I enter into separate agreements or understandings with users outside the scope of the license?
>
> A: Yes. CC licenses are nonexclusive. Licensors always have the option of entering into different, separate arrangements for the sharing of their works in addition to applying a CC license.

That means that we, who license content to Stack Exchange, are supposed to **retain the rights to our own work**, to publish it whichever other way we please, for example on our blog, without having to attribute Stack Exchange.

Now by requiring attribution *even for our own content* posted on the network, the clause effectively takes away that non-exclusivity. (or at least tries to.)  This changes the nature of the license fundamentally, and may even be in violation of Creative Commons' terms of use - as long as the limitation is there, they may not be [allowed to use the Creative Commons logo and license:](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_enter_into_separate_agreements_or_understandings_with_users_outside_the_scope_of_the_license.3F)

> Problems arise when licensors design those terms or arrangements to serve not as separate, alternative licensing arrangements but as supplemental terms having the effect of changing the standard terms within the CC license. Except in the limited situation where more permissions are being granted, **if the additional arrangement modifies or conflicts with the CC license terms then the resulting licensing arrangement is no longer a CC licensing arrangement.** In those instances, to avoid confusion by those who may mistakenly believe the work is licensed under standard CC terms, **we must insist licensors not use our trademarks, names and logos in connection with their custom licensing arrangement.**

I know this isn't a sneaky scheme to take away our rights through the small print, but right now, *technically,* that seems to be exactly what it's doing. Unless there is some super powerful good legal reason for it that no one of us can think of, it needs to go.

Disclaimer: I am eight lawyers.

I sucked a lawyer's toes once and her powers were transferred to me. That's how it works, right?

1. All lawyers always lie.
2. I am a lawyer.

Comment: Wow - good point (or at least says the micro-psuedo-lawyer in me).

Comment: You can be a lawyer who sometimes lies, or not a lawyer who lies. **I DEMAND BETTER CONUNDRUMS**, ahem, my appologies, got a little over excited

Comment: You always lie?? So those *aren't* authentic gucci bags!

Answer (score -6):

> Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.

*There is a lot of hubbub in the contents which I suspect stem from a misunderstanding of what the license concept is, and what the responsibilities of each party is under the TOS. Finally I will explain what the consequences of not following this statement would be.*

## Executive Summary

You own the right to your content.

By posting you agree to give Stack Exchange the right to license that content as a part of a collective work under the CC-BY license.

Stack Exchange owns the right to the collective work of Stack Exchange.

If you don't follow the rules, they can terminate your access.

There is no risk to having this statement in there, while the removal may create issues with enforcement of the copyright of Stack Exchange when going after sites plagiarizing material.

## General Overview of the License

I create content. It is mine.

I license that content to SE under the terms of the [Stack Exchange TOS](https://stackexchange.com/legal) with the following restrictions:

1. SE can use the content in all sorts of ways even if the Subscriber decide to delete the content later<sup>1</sup>, including the right to claim copyright over the entire content of the Stack Exchange Network as a collective work/compilation<sup>2</sup>
2. The Subscriber is responsible for making sure SE can use the content in all those ways<sup>3</sup>

<sup>1: *"You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You."*</sup>

<sup>2: *"The Network is protected by copyright as a collective work and/or compilation, pursuant to U.S. copyright laws, international conventions, and other copyright laws."*</sup>

<sup>3: *"Subscriber warrants, represents and agrees Subscriber has the right to grant Stack Exchange and the Network the rights set forth above."*</sup>

SE then licenses the content we license to them with the following restrictions:

> In the event that You post or otherwise use Subscriber Content outside of the Network or Services, whether such Subscriber Content was created by You or others, You agree that You will follow the attribution rules of the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license as follows:
>
> a) You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually displays or otherwise indicates the source of the Subscriber Content as coming from the Stack Exchange Network. This requirement is satisfied with a discreet text blurb, or some other unobtrusive but clear visual indication.
>
> b) You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content includes a hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site on the Network (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
>
> c) You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually display or otherwise clearly indicate the author names for every question and answer so used.
>
> d) You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content Hyperlink each author name directly back to his or her user profile page on the source site on the Network (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username), directly to the Stack Exchange domain, in standard HTML (i.e. not through a Tinyurl or other such indirect hyperlink, form of obfuscation or redirection), without any “nofollow” command or any other such means of avoiding detection by search engines, and visible even with JavaScript disabled.

## So Who Owns the Content?

As [Richard Tingle brings up in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220332/richard-tingle):

> which part of that gives them the pursuit power? [under the DMCA or otherwise to make claims on misuse of licensed material]

Despite not owning the copyright to Subscriber Content, they *do* own the right to the content as a *Collective Work*. As stated on [copyright.gov](http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl104.html):

> Under the present copyright law, the copyright in a separate contribution to a published collective work such as a periodical is distinct from the copyright in the collective work as a whole. In the absence of an express transfer from the author of the individual article, the copyright owner in the collective work is presumed to have acquired only the privilege of using the contribution in the collective work and in subsequent revisions and later editions of the collective work.

<sup>This is a normal English explanation of [US Title 17 Sections 102-103](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#103)</sup>

This allows SE to manage the rights to the collective work, including issuing takedown notices for content shared through SE even though they are not the owner of the individual works (the Subscriber Content).

## So Why Can't They Just Change the TOS?

[As Pekka states in the comments:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138112/probably-pekka):

> What if Stack Exchange goes bankrupt, and its stakeholders decide to sell it to some sort of troll company to raise at least some money, which then starts suing authors for violating the T&C? I don't think that's ever going to happen. But the deal has always been, "the stuff you post here is under a super transparent, honest license"

The license extended to Stack Exchange is for use in a Collective Work over which Stack Exchange has a license -- this does **not** override individual license for the individual Subscriber Content submitted by each Original Author.

Since SE never owned the rights to the Subscriber Content, as long as you are not using any other content (be it designs, layout, etc. provided by SE) that SE does have a right to, they wouldn't be able to get anywhere.

Any malicious new SE overlord would go after:

1. People using uniquely SE content (logos, layout)
2. People using 'collective work' (full question-answer threads)
3. People using individual contributions from other users

From this perspective, even an evil overlord with unlimited resources would probably place going after users reposting their own content elsewhere last, as it is the content to which SE has the least claim over (read: no claim). Even the third item on that list is a huge stretch, as the individual contribution (Subscriber Content) has a copyright owned by the Original Author, and not Stack Exchange.

It would also be absurdly easy for me, as the author, to point at the TOS and explain that SE is suing me for re-using my own original content to which I never transferred the rights.

If you want to be extra safe (read: paranoid) you should:

1. Keep identifiable records showing you as the content creator with date and time showing creation prior to posting on Stack Exchange
2. For all posts where you have not done the first step, follow the rules in the SE TOS for properly attributing posts you have made (since they are already available CC-BY, no harm in providing them CC-BY elsewhere)

## What are the Consequences Anyway?

So let's say this really evil corporation takes over, and decides that you haven't properly attributed your own Subscriber Content that you are the Original Author of. What can they actually do about it?

> Stack Exchange may also terminate or suspend any and all Services and access to the Network immediately, without prior notice or liability, if Subscriber breaches any of the terms or conditions of this Agreement. Upon termination of Subscriber's account, Subscriber’s right to use the Services, access the Network, and any Content will immediately cease.

So they could terminate your access to the service and your account. This is not the end of the world. An evil organization who co-opts Stack Exchange could do that anyway without any need to show your violation as explained here:

> Although Stack Exchange and the Network will make reasonable efforts to store and preserve the material residing on the Network, neither Stack Exchange nor the Network is responsible or liable in any way for the failure to store, preserve or access Subscriber Content or other materials you transmit or archive on the Network. You are strongly urged to take measures to preserve copies of any data, material, content or information you post or upload on the Network.
>
> The Services, Content, Network and any Software are provided on an "as is" basis, without warranties of any kind, either express or implied, including, without limitation, implied warranties of merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose or non-infringement. Stack Exchange makes no representations or warranties of any kind with respect to the Network, the Services, including any representation or warranty that the use of the Network or Services will (a) be timely, uninterrupted or error-free or operate in combination with any other hardware, software, system or data, (b) meet your requirements or expectations, (c) be free from errors or that defects will be corrected, (d) be free of viruses or other harmful components.

Comment: `Why not just post a link to the SE post which will give it more exposure and help out people who want to reuse it?` Because being *legally obliged* to do that wasn't the deal. The CC license is explicitly non-exclusive, and that's a core part of the agreement.

Comment: I've never said I think that clause was put there with some nefarious purpose in mind. But it clearly violates the spirit of SE's agreement with its users - completely needlessly. It needs to be removed.

Comment: Ignoring it is a risk to my SE account (however small) and complying impinges on my freedoms unnecessarily. All in all, it's something I'd sooner argue be removed than just leave it be.

Comment: What if Stack Exchange goes bankrupt, and its stakeholders decide to sell it to some sort of troll company to raise at least *some* money, which then starts suing authors for violating the T&C? I don't think that's ever going to happen. But the deal has always been, "the stuff you post here is under a super transparent, honest license"

Comment: It seems like a slightly odd position to suggest something was explicitly put into the terms of service, but don’t worry, they don’t mean it really

Comment: @jmac *but the lawsuit might not be fraudulent.* That's the problem of that clause.

Comment: @Oli: As far as your account is concerned, note that the ToS says, just above the clause we're discussing, that "_Stack Exchange reserves the right to [...] suspend or terminate Subscriber’s right to use the Services at any time [...] for any reason [...], or for no reason at all._" They don't _need_ that clause to ban you if they feel like it. (That said, I do agree that this clause needs to be fixed.)

Comment: @jmac All that would require to defeat is logging in as me on stack overflow and saying "I'm that guy off of that blog" on your profile

Comment: @jmac but that's not the point. There is the real risk that any content I post on SO is from then on subject to attribution forever.  I cannot publish it anywhere else without linking to Stack Overflow. That's *not* in the Creative Commons license. And I'm not at all sure about whether jurisprudence follows the "but I published it elsewhere first" logic.

Comment: @jmac I can't see anything reasonable in taking away the Creative Commons license's non-exclusivity. No matter for what reason. As said, I'm 100% sure this is for no nefarious purpose. But it's wrong and needs to be removed.

Comment: @jmac That sound like "Don't worry, the contact says X, but thats just for the paperwork, actually it'll be Y" salesman talk to me

Comment: @jmac Drafting could easily be faked. I would have to take extraordinary steps (print, mail to self, wait, store) before every post in order to truly prove my right to repost the content unhindered. It's extreme but that's the point of legal ambiguities... There's just no reason the clause needs to be in there.

Comment: `Why is this preferable?` because it's what the CC license says that we're told is being used, for one. And I don't really follow the violation argument - I'm having a hard time seeing any large-scale abuse of the site where someone says for 5 million posts, "I wrote them all." (But it's admittedly not a *completely* ridiculous reason to have that in there, hadn't thought about htat)

Comment: @jmac My brother uses this argument; that doing the right thing is inconvenient and therefore can't be the right thing (he's remarkably pro companies being allowed to lie, because doing otherwise would hurt profits)

Comment: @jmac But thats the whole problem, with these terms of service I **cannot enforce** what I had previously been led to believe were my rights regarding my content

Comment: @jmac I'm sure you are right with this (and that's probably why it was put in there), but IMO it still is an unacceptable infringement of posters' rights - and possibly even a breach of the conditions of the CC license.

Comment: @jmac Yes as a last resort, you still have a last resort don't you? You don't just say; the contract is the last resort anyway so we won't worry about what it says.

Comment: @jmac Frankly it's murky enough whether they can enforce copyright over another site. They are not the copyright owners, nor is there a clause that gives them permission to act on our behalf. When they do attack another site it would need to be under the guise of protecting the copyright they own which is the collection of items, not the items themselves. The debated clause has zero effect on that.

Comment: @jmac No, but I am quite involved with free software... I have read around the subject. Copyright infringement cases are either brought by the state for criminal cases, the copyright **holder** (not SE in terms of a post, they are just a licensee) or somebody legally representing the copyright holder, which, as I'm pointing out, is again, not Stack Exchange.

Comment: @jmac (is legitimately interested) which part of that gives them the pursuit power?

Comment: To rephrase my own counter-argument to the above, SE is the copyright holder for the work that is defined by a page of a question and its answers. If they can prove it a work, they can enforce copyright on that. But little else.

Comment: And by extension, this is why so many major open source projects require their contributors to assign copyright (or the right to represent) before their submissions are accepted.

Comment: (not having read the other comments) At first I agreed with this answer, but after thinking about it a bit, it has the feel of "it's okay to break the law, since no-one will catch you" (i.e. not good).

Comment: Just to be clear, I can't see how that line has any connection to our work encouraging... "mirror sites"... to follow the CC-BY-SA attribution rules. It'd have to be a site composed entirely of someone's own work on SE, at which point... Who cares? The rest of that section *does* lay out our expectations for attribution (which CC does provide some support for providing); as I said above, I *suspect* the wording in question was aimed at something else (let's call it [the Writers problem](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/167)) but... Will get some clarification on that.

Comment: Having read it before and after: I am leaving my downvote on this answer. "Don't worry about it" is not a good attitude to take with a line of a _legal agreement_ that should not be there. If the line needs any defending, I'd rather hear the defence from Stack Exchange's legal or pseudo-legal team.

Comment: @jmac What I think is that you just created and responded to a straw man rather than me, and were a bit condescending.

Comment: @jmac You are misunderstanding me and responding to things I didn't say: "you still think that this is a *Serious Problem*™" / "I don't think this is a major issue". I have not made an statement to suggest I believe it is either of these things - you were the one to suggest I think it's a severe problem or major issue, not I. We are not in disagreement. This term is, however, concerning to me.

Comment: @jmac I think what Jonathan is saying is that not only serious problems need sorting out

Comment: That is my position, yes. If it's concerning, we should address it, and not being a serious problem doesn't invalidate peoples' concern about it or mean it shouldn't be addressed. In fact, if it's not yet a serious problem, now is a _really good_ time to address it. It might not _become_ a serious problem, but see second sentence.

Comment: Your edit makes more sense legally speaking now but the question isn't about copying an entire thread, it's about using just the content I've posted elsewhere needing to attribute SE for my *work* and without the risk having my account shut down.

Comment: You may have more knowledge in this than me, but how do you get the idea that all the hypothetical evil corporation can do in response to an infringement is ban me from the site? I did breach their terms of service, a contract. Why would that not give them a case in civil court?

Comment: They could have a go at suing for loss of earnings through basic contract law. By agreeing to the TOS, you're agreeing to give them a link. By not giving them a link, you're depriving them.

Comment: With the new answer from Jaydles this whole thing seems to have been a mistake

Comment: @jmac re "subscriber content" - the content would be 100% identical and as you say, it would be difficult to prove where it was published first. But different jurisdictions may put the burden of proof on different parties. Can you guarantee for sure that it'll always play out on the user's side everywhere in the world?

Comment: @jmac it seems like you're being deliberately argumentative now. The TOS is a contract. By not following it (posting without attribution) you are in material breach. If this is all new to you, probably best starting at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_contract_law#Breach_of_contract

Comment: @Oli, I have spent my time, as someone very familiar with contracts, to try to explain what the current license says, what laws it relates to, and why this line isn't of serious concern. I'm sorry you can't appreciate the effort or the information I provided at face value. I would have loved it if you tried to understand how the law works rather than just looking stuff up on wikipedia to prove a point, and I would have truly appreciated it if you had refrained from calling me argumentative in the same breath. Disagreement is fine, how you did it rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: @jmac That stance, deleting your comments and the header on your newest revision collectively leave me aghast. The insinuation that the "misunderstanding" has been anything but yours is insulting. **Your answer is built out of our comments** and even after all of that, you're still pulling out the wrong conclusion. It's quite amazing. I'm glad we've had this conversion as I've been able to reaffirm what I already knew but my appreciation ends well before giving you credit for what others and I have said.

Comment: Imagine Jon Skeet compiling a hardcover or E-Book with his best Stack Overflow answers, and failing to attribute every one as the CC-Wiki license requires. That might make a worthy target for a troll company, wouldn't you agree? Not that I think this will ever happen - but why take the risk?

Comment: @probablyPekka This is where we disagree. What makes even that most extreme example a worthy target? The company would have to (A) prove that Jon Skeet took the posts from Subscriber Content and not from any other source (challenging since he wrote it), (B) prove that there were damages from him publishing his own content outside the Q&A format that SE uses to make money. If an evil empire ever decides to make frivolous lawsuits, they'd start with ones that had a chance to actually make money -- not people using their own content elsewhere.

Comment: @jmac `prove that Jon Skeet took the posts from Subscriber Content` again - how do you know on which party the onus of proving this falls in every jurisdiction in the world? And technically, if Jon writes an answer on SO, then that's where it was first published. That seems easily provable. I know the whole scenario is super unlikely - but why have even this small risk in the small print when there is absolutely no need to have it, and it is possibly a violation of the CC license?

Comment: @probablyPekka, from the TOS: *"This Agreement shall be governed by and construed in accordance with the laws of the state of Delaware"* For civil cases in jurisdictions in the US, the burden of proof is on the plaintiff to establish their claim (tie goes to the defendant). Contract common sense 101 is that there is absolutely no way to 100% eliminate all risk via contract language (just like you cannot make a 100% safe product). If you are afraid of risk, delete your account now as that is the only way to minimize your risk in regards to using the site.

Comment: @jmac that's disingenuous. There is "leaving the house is dangerous" risk, and there is "there's a clause that takes away a right that I was told I had" risk. Re jurisdictions - that's fine, but what if the infraction takes place in Europe? Either way, I don't think we are going to agree on this. Let's see what Stack Exchange are going to do; what Jaydles posted looks pretty good.

Comment: @probablyPekka I [made a room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11275/room-for-jmac-and-pekka-) to explain the concept. Feel free to join (or just read after I write what is far too long for comments), or ignore as you see fit.