# Using a question as the basis of an article elsewhere

Tags: discussion, copyright

I remember sometime reading that SO owns the copyright to my questions. However, in this case I posted the question merely to garner opinions on a system of doing things. One very good opinion makes me want to write an article on Code Project outlining the system. What attributions and or permissions do I need to do that?

Comment: If you are talking about your own content, [Can you ditch the attribution for own content clause from the Terms of Service?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203209/182513) is very relavant, especially, [Jaydles♦ answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203299/182513), but if you are talking about answers to your questions then @ShadowWizard's duplicate is spot on

Comment: SE doesn't own the copyright to content you've posted. You give them the right to publish it under the CC licence with attribution.

Comment: I'm talking strictly about the content in the question only, which is purely my invention. I only posted it to ask opinions on it and whether I was doing anything really wrong.

Comment: @ProfK if it is the question content, then read Jaydles answer I linked above.  The Terms of Service now explicitly say you are free to use your own content as you see fit without requiring any attribution